# Can I make cross domain requests from a XUL application using browser control?

Tags: browser, cross-domain, xul

I am trying to use the browser tag of XUL framework https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser. The I have set type='chrome' and attribute disablesecurity='true'. But I get the error 'Access to restricted URI denied code: "1012"'.

Is there any way to overcome the same-origin-policy security sandbox. This is a custom app and I would like it to not have such restriction.

Comment: The `disablesecurity="true"` attribute only turns off the `onSecurityChange` SSL notifications that are used e.g. to update the lock icon, warn about insecure form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, but I don't think I've ever done it.  Perhaps you should [use the PrivilegeManager here](https://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/jssec.html#privs).